# How to fill the plot like this?

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[-x^3 + 2 x^2 + 8 x, {x, -5, 5}, Filling -> Axis]
```

produces this

[image]

What's the easiest way to change to something like this

[image]

That is, I only need the two "humps".

I have tried this:

```
Show[
    Plot[-x^3 + 2 x^2 + 8 x, {x, -5, 5}],
    Plot[-x^3 + 2 x^2 + 8 x, {x, -2, 4}, Filling -> Axis]
]
```

which gives what I want, but it looks too dumb ... and there must be an easier way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Plot[{-x^3 + 2 x^2 + 8 x, ConditionalExpression[-x^3 + 2 x^2 + 8 x, -2 <= x <= 4]}, 
 {x, -5, 5}, 
Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]